# Symfony: Unable to render image in pdf file

Tags: symfony, dompdf

I am using dompdf in Symfony project to render PDF

```
$pdfOptions = new Options();
$pdfOptions->set('defaultFont', 'Arial');
$pdfOptions->setIsPhpEnabled(true);
$pdfOptions->setIsRemoteEnabled(true);

$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->setOptions($pdfOptions);
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("mypdf.pdf");
```

Same image is showing on webpage but not in pdf. What am I missing?

Comment: This kind of error often happen when the route to your image is fine in your webpage but not in your pdf, try modifying the route to an absolute url in your pdf and see what happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

```
    $options = new Options();
    $options->setIsRemoteEnabled(true);
    $pdfInvoice = new Dompdf($options);
    $body = $this->renderView('App/Payments/invoice.html.twig');

    $pdfInvoice->loadHtml($body);
    $pdfInvoice->setPaper('A4');
    $pdfInvoice->render();
    $pdfInvoice->stream();

    return new Response($pdfInvoice->output());
```

also set absolute path in your template e.g

```
<img src="{{ asset('assets/img/logo.png', absolute=true) }}">
```